# Android Drawing text on canvas

Tags: android

I am drawing a speedometer on a ImageView that contains the bg. I use this code for the ticks and the values

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 270; i += 5) {
        if (i % 30 == 0) {
            scalePaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
            canvas.drawLine(3.55f * wQuarter, 2 * hQuarter,
                    3.78f * wQuarter, 2 * hQuarter, scalePaint);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(i), 3.5f * wQuarter,
                    2f * hQuarter, scalePaint);


        } else {
            scalePaint.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
            canvas.drawLine(3.65f * wQuarter, 2 * hQuarter,
                    3.78f * wQuarter, 2 * hQuarter, scalePaint);

        }
        canvas.rotate(5f, 2 * wQuarter, 2 * hQuarter);
    }
```

the ticks are drawn as they should, but the problem is the text is also rotated with the canvas. How can I keep the text position while resetting its rotation? most of it is upside down or at +90 -90

here it is[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Draw the text after you rotate.  Multiple the position you want to draw it at by the rotation matrix of your rotation to get the new position to draw at

Comment: can you explain that a little deeper? Geometry was never good to me

Answer (score 0):

you can use canvas.save() to save the status of the variables affecting the canvas (rotation, distortion, ...), then canvas.restore() to return to that status.
So in you case you need to rearrange the content of your for loop a little bit to do this :

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(...);
{draw the line}
canvas.restore();
canvas.drawText(...);
```

Comment: isn't that a bit too hungry?

Comment: also, this doesn't work, if you save->rotate->restore you arrive where you started